# What publicly accessible vantage points exist near Cabo San Lucas?

Tags: vantage-points, los-cabos

I'm currently staying in Cabo San Lucas and I would like to take a nice panoramic photo of the city. What are my options location-wise for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy option is to hike up Mt Solmar (Ascenso al Cerro del Vigía). Every day at 8:30am, a local guy named Enrique leads groups of tourists up the mountain from [this location](https://goo.gl/maps/MCYt3iSibyBqk6gw6). It is a dog training camp, so you will have a few friendly dogs accompanying you during the hike up the mountain. Enrique doesn't charge anything for leading the tours, but a tip is welcome - I've personally left 50 pesos. The hike is of moderate difficulty and should be accessible to any adults without health issues. The entire hike up the mountain and back took us 1.5 hours, so you'll be done by 10am.

Once you hike up the mountain, you'll get a great view of Cabo San Lucas and the surrounding bay. You can view more photos from the [hike's official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Ascenso-al-Cerro-del-Vig%C3%ADa-259269378107169/?eid=ARDqJ7rkxtpzLBwQbKHKzjL5jsLqkwtWIu117o9Pstngp0077eWxO2aLN5f3op2MQvUgaF4PU86g17tQ).

[image]